# How to know if a merge is ongoing in git

Tags: git

I use a script to manage my development process. Some times I need to know if a merge is pending.

I use to use "git ls-files --unmerged", but it does not work when conflicts has been resolved and the unmerged files added to the index.

In that case, is there a way to know if a merge is ongoing ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From a script: look if `"$(git rev-parse --git-dir)"/MERGE_HEAD` exists (that is how `__git_ps1` does it).

---

Manually, I let the repo status show in my prompt.

`__git_ps1` has very useful features. Beside showing you your current branch, status, index status, remote tracking branch status on your command line prompt, it tells you if you have a merge ongoing.

You can find an instruction [there](http://code-worrier.com/blog/git-branch-in-bash-prompt/).

In short, [download git-prompt.sh](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh), put it in your `PATH`, source it in your `~/.bashrc`, use `__git_ps1` in your `PS1` in `~/.bashrc`.

Read the comment at the top of git-prompt.sh for additional features.

An example:

```
gauthier@sobel:~/tmp/sigrt_val (master *) $
```

(shows current branch `master`, and that I have local changes `*`)

Another example with a conflicting merge:

```
gauthier@sobel:~/tmp/sigrt_val (two) $ git merge one
Auto-merging test.c
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in test.c
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
gauthier@sobel:~/tmp/sigrt_val (two *+|MERGING) $
```

(`*` for local changes, `+` for staged files, `|MERGING` for currently in an unfinished merge)

Comment: Thank you. I look if .git/MERGE_HEAD exist.

Answer (score 4):

If you are in the middle of a non-fast-forward merge that has conflicts, then [`git status` alone](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging#Basic-Merge-Conflicts) can inform you of your current state.

From the site:

```
$ git status
On branch master
You have unmerged paths.
  (fix conflicts and run "git commit")
```

If you've finished up the conflicts, you'll likely see a message like this:

```
$ git status
On branch master
All conflicts fixed but you are still merging.
  (use "git commit" to conclude merge)
```

The `__git_ps1` script is a wonderful visual convenience, but it's still standing on the shoulders of the standard metadata that can be found in other parts of Git.